# Core Data: NSPredicate for many-to-many relationship. ("to-many key not allowed here")

Tags: core-data, ios, nspredicate

I have two entities named "Category" and "Article" which have a many to many relationship. I want to form a predicate which searches for all articles where category.name is equal to some value. I have the following:

```
 NSEntityDescription  *entityArticle   = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Article" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]; 
 NSSortDescriptor  *sortDescriptor   = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
 NSArray     *sortDescriptors  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
 NSPredicate    *predicate    = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categories.name == [cd] %@", category.name]; 

 [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
 [request setEntity:entityArticle];
 [request setPredicate:predicate];

 NSMutableArray *results = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil] mutableCopy];

 if ([results count] > 0)
  NSLog(@"Results found."); 
 else 
  NSLog(@"NO results found."); 

 [request release];
 [sortDescriptor release];
 [sortDescriptors release];
```

The error I receive is `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'`

Are there any options to retrieve the desired data?

Comment: A SUBQUERY may also be what you need.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346546/core-data-unsupported-predicate-with-all-and-in

Comment: FRESH INFO:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60637295/294884

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You're trying to compare a collection (`categories.name`) to a scalar value (`category.name`).  You need to either use a collection comparator (`CONTAINS`), or use a predicate modifier (`ANY`/`ALL`/`SOME`, etc).

Try using:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY categories.name =[cd] %@", category.name];
```

Or:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categories.name CONTAINS[cd] %@", category.name];
```

Comment: This works for me, both with and without the '[cd]'. Can you elaborate on the function of that?

Comment: @DuncanBabbage the `[cd]` means to do a case-insensitive (the `c`) and a diacritic-insensitive (the `d`) search.

Comment: It's not working if `category` has inverse `to one` relation to 'Article'. Any idea how to predicate that ?

Answer (score 11):

**SWIFT SYNTAX**

In case anyone happens upon this writing in swift as I did...

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY categories.name = %@", category.name!)
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For those who faced the same problem. You can use **IN** operator instead of **= / ==** to look for specific objects in any Collection.
Look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795) for reference. *No difference Swift or Objective-C*