# Core Data unsupported predicate with ALL and IN

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have a request like this :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY attributes.attribute.attributeId IN %@", attributeIds];
```

That will return a list of objects, that have one ore more of the attributes I set. I want to get a list of objects that have all the attributes I pass, so I tried :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL attributes.attribute.attributeId IN %@", attributeIds];
```

But I got an exception :

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate (null)'
```

Anyway, I'm not even sure that this is the right request. Say that I have at list of attributes : `[red, green, blue]`, <strike>How can I get all objects that have at least those attributes ?</strike>

```
* Object_1 (red, green, blue)
* Object_2 (red, green, blue, yellow, brown)
* Object_3 (red, green blue, black, brown)
```

but not `Object_4 (red, green, yellow)` because it doesn't have the `blue` attribute (note that I get all 4 objects with my `ANY` fetch request, as expected)

<strike>edit, related question : what if I want a full match ? So for `[red, green, blue]` I will only get `Object_1` ?</strike>

---

edit 2 : I managed to answer both questions, but [I have a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374667/core-data-match-a-to-many-relationship-to-a-list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Fetch all Objects that have at least all attributes in list

```
NSPredicate *objectsThatContainsAtLeastAllAttributesInList =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
        @"SUBQUERY(attributes, $s, $s.attribute.attributeId IN %@).@count == %d", attributeIds, [attributeIds count]];
```

### Fetch all Objects that have only the attributes in list

```
NSPredicate *objectsWhoseAttributesAreInList =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
        @"attributes.@count == %d AND SUBQUERY(attributes, $s, $s.attributes.id IN %@).@count == %d", [attributeIds count], attributeIds, [attributeIds count]];
```