# Core Data match a to many relationship to a list

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-data

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346546/core-data-unsupported-predicate-with-all-and-in/11374645#11374645), it occured a new one :

Say I have these Attributes : `[red, green, blue]` How can I fetch objects whose some or all attributes are in list, **but in this list only** ?

```
* Object_1 (red, green, blue)
* Object_2 (red, green)
* Object_3 (red)
```

This means not fetch `Object_4 (red, green, blue, yellow)` because it has `yellow` which is not in the list

Answer (score 0):

you can make a compound predicate which can add your 3 predicates :

```
NSPredicate *predOne = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"color == %@",@"red"];
NSPredicate *predTwo = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"color == %@",@"blue"];
NSPredicate *predThree = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"color == %@",@"green"];
NSArray *allPredicates = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:predOne,predTwo,predThree, nil];
NSPredicate finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:allPredicates];
```