# coredata keypath nameOfMovie not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Theaters id=3>

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, core-data

I have a coredata project and I'm trying to make a query. Here is my coredata model:

[image]

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *theaterDescription = [ NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Theaters" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

     NSPredicate *theaterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nameOfTheater like %@ AND nameOfMovie like %@",_theaterName,_movieOutlet.stringValue];


    NSFetchRequest *theaterRequestTwo = [NSFetchRequest new];
    theaterRequestTwo.entity = theaterDescription;
    theaterRequestTwo.predicate = theaterPredicate;



    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *theaterResults = [moc executeFetchRequest:theaterRequestTwo error:&error];
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
keypath nameOfMovie not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Theaters id=3>
```

I also tried :

```
NSPredicate *theaterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nameOfTheater like %@ AND Movies.nameOfMovie like %@",_theaterName,_movieOutlet.stringValue];
```

But I got this error:

```
keypath Movies.nameOfMovie not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Theaters id=3>
```

And I also tried:

```
NSPredicate *theaterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nameOfTheater like %@ AND movies.nameOfMovie like %@",_theaterName,_movieOutlet.stringValue];
```

I got the following error:

to-many key not allowed here

By any chance any of you knows what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing on my code. I'll really appreciate your help.

**UPDATE:**

This are the headers files for my coredata model:

theaters classe:

```
@class Movies;

@interface Theaters : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * nameOfTheater;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *movies;
@end

@interface Theaters (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addMoviesObject:(Movies *)value;
- (void)removeMoviesObject:(Movies *)value;
- (void)addMovies:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeMovies:(NSSet *)values;
```

---

Movies class:

```
@class Schedules, Theaters;

@interface Movies : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * nameOfMovie;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *showTimes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Theaters *theaters;
@end

@interface Movies (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addShowTimesObject:(Schedules *)value;
- (void)removeShowTimesObject:(Schedules *)value;
- (void)addShowTimes:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeShowTimes:(NSSet *)values;
```

---

Schedules class:

```
@interface Schedules : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * showTimes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *movie;
@end

@interface Schedules (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addMovieObject:(Movies *)value;
- (void)removeMovieObject:(Movies *)value;
- (void)addMovie:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeMovie:(NSSet *)values;
```

Comment: The last solution seems to be the good hint to follow. Your issue is explained there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217849/core-data-nspredicate-for-many-to-many-relationship-to-many-key-not-allowed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `SUBQUERY` for this kind of problems

one exact theater entity (copied by your example)

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nameOfTheater like %@ AND SUBQUERY(movies, $mv, $mv.nameOfMovie like %@).@count > 0", _theaterName,_movieOutlet.stringValue];
```

**UPDATE**

all theaters where movie abc is running

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(movies, $mv, $mv.nameOfMovie CONTAINS[c] %@).@count > 0", @"abc"];
```

btw, is you model correct?

```
Theaters <->> Movies = 1:n
```

So every `Theater` has x `Movies`, but a `Movie` is running in only one `Theater`
So if you fetch a `Movie` with name "abc" you can get the `Theater` as attibute. Or is it

```
Theaters <<->> Movies = n:m
```

? so `movies` and `movieTheaters` are `NSSet<Movie>/NSSet<Theater>`

**UPDATE 2**

still need an answer for the question above. what is the correct relation between? is one movie in x theaters or only in one. how are your header files for the ManagedObject classes? ;)

```
NSEntityDescription *schedulesDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Schedules" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

// something like this if 1:n. Try and post logs, have no IDE at the moment
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"movie.nameOfMovie == %@ AND movie.movieTheaters.nameOfTheater == %@", @"movie8", @"theaterOne"];

// if n:m, as far as I remember you couldn't fetch over 2 n:m relations via .
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"movie.nameOfMovie == %@ AND SUBQUERY(movie, $mv, $mv.movieTheaters.nameOfTheater == %@).@count > 0", @"movie8", @"theaterOne"];
```

Comment: thank you for answer but I'm looking for the exact match. For example I have theaterOne showing Movie4. With the query you give I get the theater name and also the array of movies. Do you know how can I build the query just get the name of theater matching movie?

Comment: I can do everything xP but please explain more, I cannot follow you ^^ Do you want one theater entity or an array of all theaters where the movie is running? ^^ if second, I will update my answer

Comment: each theater has movies and when and I need to query the name of the theater and movie to get all details of that pair. For example if theater named "theaterOne" is showing movie named "movie8" and I query for that NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nameOfTheater like %@ AND SUBQUERY(movies, $mv, $mv.nameOfMovie like %@).@count > 0", @"theaterOne",@"movie8"]; <-- but in this case the result array I get all the movies showing in theaterOne.

Comment: you will always get the type of entity that is defined in the `NSEntityDescription`. So if you want to fetch `Movies` you have to change the description and the predicate. I update my answer so you can see how a fetch for schedules could look like