# CoreData: Using NSPredicate to filter one to many to many relationship (error to-many key not allowed here)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have coreData model:

[image]

I'm trying to verify the schedule of the movie match the movie and theater but I'm getting the error "to-many key not allowed here"

Here is my code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *timeDescription = [ NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Schedules" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSPredicate *timePredicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"showTimes <= %@", _movieTime];
    NSPredicate *moviePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY movie.nameOfMovie CONTAINS[cd] %@", _movie];
    NSPredicate *theatersPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"movie.theaters.nameOfTheater == %@", _theaterName];
    NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[timePredicate,moviePredicate,theatersPredicate]];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest new];
    request.predicate = compoundPredicate;
    request.entity = timeDescription;
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *result = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

If I only use the following predicates:

```
NSPredicate *timePredicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"showTimes <= %@", _movieTime];
NSPredicate *moviePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY movie.nameOfMovie CONTAINS[cd] %@", _movie];
```

I can get the match with the schedule and the movie but my questions is how can I get match for schedule and movies and theaters any of you knows what I'm doing wrong?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: why you don't just extend the predicate of the answer I gave you with the SUBQUERY in your other question? If it worked fine, just add a further AND condition with the time

Comment: Kind of duplicate? Since you got the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436816/coredata-keypath-nameofmovie-not-found-in-entity-nssqlentity-theaters-id-3 ?

Comment: @geo, the problem I have is how to reach back when my entity is "Schedules" to the "Theaters".  NSPredicate *theatersPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"movie.theaters.nameOfTheater == %@", _theaterName]; .

Comment: @Lame, this is total different issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the "to-many key not allowed here" error because, in your `theatersPredicate` "movie" is a to-many relationship.  Compare with your `moviePredicate`, which works OK because it uses the "ANY" keyword.

So you might be tempted to just add "ANY" to your `theatersPredicate`.  That will work (i.e. compile and run OK), but will not, I think, give you the results you are looking for: it will show those where "(ANY movies' moviename matches) and (ANY movies' nameOfTheatre matches)".  But it could be a different Movie in each case.

What I think you want is "ANY movies where (moviename matches AND nameOfTheatre matches)".  For that purpose, use SUBQUERY:

```
NSPredicate *timePredicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"showTimes <= %@", _movieTime];
NSPredicate *movieAndTheaterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(movie, $x, $x.nameOfMovie CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND $x.theaters.nameOfTheater == %@).@count > 0", _movie, _theaterName];
NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[timePredicate,movieAndTheaterPredicate]];
```

Comment: Sorry, typographical error (a superfluous " in the predicate) has now been removed.