# coredata fault messages

Tags: xcode, core-data, ios5

I am printing the contents of a managed record to a file. I have one main entity, say, MyAppEntity, and several related entities (People, Place, etc).

I am seeing this output from the file:

```
/Users/david/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/C9ACA218-F2D6-4623-8CAF-5FE763D10FC8/Documents/
 MyApp-0001 12.01.25 
 Summary goes here... 
 Nothing here yet. 
 Relationship 'people' on managed object (0x79eaf7f0) <NSManagedObject: 0x79eaf7f0> (entity: MyAppEntity; id: 0x79eae950 <x-coredata:/B86C9CA8-EDE4-452C-BA56-FEF50B4F0FF9/MyAppEntity/p1> ; data: {
    audioName = 00010125121910;
    audioNo = 0;
    date = nil;
    MyApp = "MyApp-0001 12.01.25";
    interpret = "Nothing here yet.";
    keyword =     (
    );
    order = 0;
    people =     (
        "0x79ee42f0 <x-coredata:/B86C9CA8-EDE4-452C-BA56-FEF50B4F0FF9/PeopleEntity/p1>",
        "0x79ee4300 <x-coredata:/B86C9CA8-EDE4-452C-BA56-FEF50B4F0FF9/PeopleEntity/p2>"
    );
    place =     (
        "0x79ee6970 <x-coredata:/B86C9CA8-EDE4-452C-BA56-FEF50B4F0FF9/PlaceEntity/p2>",
        "0x79ee6960 <x-coredata:/B86C9CA8-EDE4-452C-BA56-FEF50B4F0FF9/PlaceEntity/p1>"
    );
    recurring = 0;
    summary = "Summary goes here...";
    symbol =     (
    );
    type =     (
    );
}) with objects {(
    <NSManagedObject: 0x79ee47e0> (entity: PeopleEntity; id: 0x79ee42f0 <x-coredata:/B86C9CA8-EDE4-452C-BA56-FEF50B4F0FF9/PeopleEntity/p1> ; data: {
    definition = nil;
    name = me;
    order = 0;
    people = "<relationship fault: 0x79ef5ce0 'people'>";
}),
    <NSManagedObject: 0x79ee4a70> (entity: PeopleEntity; id: 0x79ee4300 <x-coredata:/B86C9CA8-EDE4-452C-BA56-FEF50B4F0FF9/PeopleEntity/p2> ; data: {
    definition = nil;
    name = you;
    order = 1;
    people = "<relationship fault: 0x79e60840 'people'>";
})
)}
```

I have two questions... First, what do the fault messages mean? and second, how can I retrieve the values for say people.name or place.name..?

I can post the data model  diagram, but it basically looks like this:

MyAppEntity: Attributes: 
  Title
  Date
  Details
Relationships people, place, etc.

PeopleEntity: Attributes:
  Name
  Description
  Order
Relationship: people

PlaceEntity: Attributes:
  Name
  Description
  Order
Relationship: place

The relationships are many to many. This is because one task can have many people and the same people can work on multiple tasks.

---

Thanks to Gerry and to Marcus Zarra in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328585/core-data-many-to-many-relationship-predicate-question). I've finally got it.. If it helps others, here is my code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];  
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *mainEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MainEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:mains]; 
    NSError *error = nil;   
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


    NSLog(@"Record Count is: %i", [fetchedObjects count]);

    // THIS ACTUALLY WORKS.....

     for (MainEntity *mains in fetchedObjects) {
     NSLog(@"Main: %@", mains.name);
         NSSet *peopleSet = [mains valueForKey:@"people"];   
         for (id person in peopleSet) {
             NSLog(@"name = %@", [person valueForKey:@"name"]);
         }
         NSSet *keywordSet = [mains valueForKey:@"keyword"];     
         for (id keyWord in keywordSet) {
             NSLog(@"Keyword = %@", [keyWord valueForKey:@"word"]);
         }
         NSSet *placeSet = [mains valueForKey:@"place"];     
         for (id places in placeSet) {
             NSLog(@"Place = %@", [places valueForKey:@"name"]);
         }
         NSSet *symbolSet = [mains valueForKey:@"symbol"];   
         for (id symbols in symbolSet) {
             NSLog(@"Symbol = %@", [symbols valueForKey:@"symbolName"]);
         }
         NSSet *typeSet = [mains valueForKey:@"type"];   
         for (id types in typeSet) {
             NSLog(@"Type = %@", [types valueForKey:@"typeName"]);
         }
     }

    if (!fetchedObjects || error) {
        NSLog(@"[ERROR] COREDATA: Fetch request raised an error - '%@'", [error description]);
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Faults are used so that data can be loaded only when it is needed. When you access the relationship, it will be loaded. See the [Faulting and Uniquing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html) in the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

Once you access the to-many relationship, you will have a set. You can enumerate over the set and access the attributes on the individual managed objects. For example (assuming appObject is an instance of MyAppEntity):

```
for (id person in [appObject valueForKey:@"people"]) {
    NSLog(@"name = %@", [person valueForKey:@"name"]);
}
```

Comment: They really should have chosen a name other tha fault. It causes a lot of confusion (judging by the number of times it comes up here, anyway!)

Comment: Thanks Gerry. I have not had my coffee yet, so please be forgiving... I have entered  this code:         NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
 
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AppEntity" 
        inManagedObjectContext:context];
 [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
 
 for (id person in entity.people ) {
  NSLog(@"name = %@", [person valueForKey:@"name"]);
 }
--- but entity.people gives me an error - Property 'people' not found on object of type 'NSEntityDescription *'

Comment: Thank you very much Gerry. After digesting through my Intel 4004 brain, I understood what you wrote. Thanks very very much... I've posted my final code above.. Let me know if you see problems with it. Again, I'm much obliged.

Comment: I don't know if I followed the correct procedure asking my question, as there are other similar questions. It did help.

Comment: Your code looks fine. I forgot to access "people" using `valueForKey:` and I have updated my answer. I almost always generate classes (using mogenerator) for my Core Data entities, so I'm used to always using properties instead of `valueForKey:`.

Comment: Thanks Gerry. I really love having others look at my code. I don't care for things that don't work, and being an indie developer, as many people who can look at my stuff, the better my products will be. Now, I will look into mogenerator.. Again, I really appreciated the help.